# How to create a centralised server

Tags: sql-server, database, web-services

I have a question out of curiosity regarding centralized databases. When you navigate through the web you can find websites that offer one particular service, like cinema movies or flight information, from multiple companies/locations.
How is this accomplished from a technical/programming point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a technical/programming perspective it can be achieved a number of ways.  Some ways include web services, FTP of files with data, screen scraping, shared DBs hosted in a public place ("cloud", if you must), people in cheap countries typing it in or one-off proprietary methods.  It depends.

The biggest challenge with these sorts of problems is rarely technical, rather the legal and financial agreements that need to be in place for the various entities to share and consume the data (and make a $ from it).  The technical stuff?  It just depends.